# Why does a swap function taking two pointers only work with using namespace std?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a bunch of code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main() {
    int a = 7;
    int b = 5;
    swap(a, b);
    cout << a << b; // prints 57 as expected
}
```

However, if I remove `using namespace std`, the compiler raises an error about `int` to `int*` conversion. Why does the code work with `using namespace std` even though I didn't use the method with the `&` operator?

Comment: Relevant: [Why is `using namespace std;` considered a bad practice in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/140719)

Comment: The second snippet does not cause compile error with my g++-5.5 and clang++-11.0.0

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In the first example, `std::swap` is called, because of your `using namespace std`.
The second example is exactly the same as the first one, so you might have no using.

Anyway, if you rename your function to `my_swap` or something like that (and change every occurence), then the first code shouldn't work, as expected. Or, remove the `using namespace std` and call `std::cin` and `std::cout` explicitly. I would recommend the second option.

Comment: @w1LL1ng try removing the `using namespace std`. In fact, never ever use that!