# Stack and Queue with parent class and virtual function

Tags: c++

One of my homework assignments is to create a hierarchy of Stack and Queue. I am required to have a superclass `DataStructure` which has member functions push and pop. pop is supposed to be declared only once within `DataStructure` while push is required to be a virtual function. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class DataStructure {
protected:
    vector<int> data;
public:
    void push(int element) { }

    int pop() {
        if (data.size() == 0)
            return -1;

        int elem = data.back();
        data.pop_back();
        return elem;
    }
};


class Stack: public DataStructure {

};


class Queue: public DataStructure {

};
```

I am stuck. I do not know how to implement the virtual function.

Comment: Check your assignment spec to see if the instructor made mention of pure virtual functions or abstract classes. If they did, you might have to take bcr's answer one step further: `virtual void push(int element) { }` becomes `virtual void push(int element)  = 0;`

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. Mainly, you are missing the `virtual` keyword in front of `void push()`.

Explicitly,

```
void push(int element) { }
```

becomes:

```
virtual void push(int element) { }
```

Or, for [a pure virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained):

```
virtual void push(int element) = 0;
```

Furthermore, you can now add `push()` to both Stack and Queue:

**Stack**

```
class Stack: public DataStructure {
public:
    void push(int element) {  
        std::cout << "inside Stack.push()";
    }
}; // Stack
```

**Queue**

```
class Queue: public DataStructure {
public:
    void push(int element) { 
        std::cout << "inside Queue.push()";
    }
}; // Stack
```

Below is a revision of your code. Keep up the good work!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class DataStructure {
protected:
    vector<int> data;
public:
    virtual void push(int element) = 0;

    int pop() {
        if (data.size() == 0)
            return -1;

        int elem = data.back();
        data.pop_back();
        return elem;
    } // pop()
}; // DataStructure


class Stack: public DataStructure {
public:
    void push(int element) {  
        std::cout << "inside Stack.push()" << std::endl;
    }
}; // Stack


class Queue: public DataStructure {
public:
    void push(int element) { 
        std::cout << "inside Queue.push()" << std::endl;
    }
}; // Queue
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use a `deque` instead of a `vector` as `deque` allows insertions and deletions from both ends. Using `vector` will be inefficient here, as you will need to use `insert` for inserting at the beginning (for Queue). Here is the quote from cplusplus:

> Because vectors use an array as their underlying storage, inserting
>   elements in positions other than the vector end causes the container
>   to relocate all the elements that were after position to their new
>   positions. This is generally an inefficient operation compared to the
>   one performed for the same operation by other kinds of sequence
>   containers

**NOTE**- Please avoid using `using namespace std`. For details refer -

- [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- The live example of problems it create:
  [How to use an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712076/how-to-use-an-iterator/2712125#2712125)
- Another example -
  [Confusion about pointers and references in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402789/confusion-about-pointers-and-references-in-c)

Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

class DataStructure {
protected:
    std::deque<int> data;
public:
    virtual void push(int element) { }

    int pop() {
        if (data.size() == 0)
            return -1;

        int elem = data.back();
        data.pop_back();
        return elem;
    }

    void print() {
        for(std::deque<int>::iterator i=data.begin();i<data.end();i++)
            std::cout << *i;
            std::cout << "\n";
    }
};


class Stack: public DataStructure {
public:
    void push(int element) {  
        data.push_back(element);
    }
}; // Stack


class Queue: public DataStructure {
public:
    void push(int element) { 
        data.push_front(element);
    }
}; // Queue

int main()
{
    Stack s;
    Queue q;
    s.push(1);
    s.print();
    s.push(2);
    s.print();
    s.push(3);
    s.push(4);
    s.print();
    s.push(5);
    s.print();
    s.pop();
    s.print();
    s.pop();
    s.print();
    s.pop();
    s.print();
    s.pop();
    s.print();
    s.pop();
    s.print();

    q.push(1);
    q.print();
    q.push(2);
    q.print();
    q.push(3);
    q.push(4);
    q.print();
    q.push(5);
    q.print();
    q.pop();
    q.print();
    q.pop();
    q.print();
    q.pop();
    q.print();
    q.pop();
    q.print();
    q.pop();
    q.print();

}
```