# cast from double* to int loses precision

Tags: c++, casting, int, double

`d` is a `double` type data and `p` is a pointer to it. When both of them are separately casted to int explicitly, it gives the following error for pointer p's cast.
:
cast from `double*` to `int` loses precision

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    double d=3.5;
    double* p=&d;
    i=(int)d;
    j=(int)p;   // this line gives the error
    cout<<i<<" "<<j;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the error there to be 
"invalid conversion from `double*` to `int`. Why is it not so?

Also, why didn't the cast for data d give the "loses precision" error if it does so for the pointer `p`?

Answer (score 2):

> I expected the error there to be "invalid conversion from 'double*' to
> 'int'". Why is it not so?

I assume it's just a compiler-dependent way of dealing with this error. On clang I get something similar, maybe more informative:

```
error: cast from pointer to smaller type 'int' loses information
```

> Also, why didn't the cast for data d give the "loses precision" error
> if it does so for the pointer p?

Conversion from a float or double to an int is among standard conversions, not erroneous and sometimes useful. This should not throw an error, more on it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion),

> A prvalue of floating-point type can be
> converted to a prvalue of any integer type. The fractional part is
> truncated, that is, the fractional part is discarded. If the value
> cannot fit into the destination type, the behavior is undefined (even
> when the destination type is unsigned, modulo arithmetic does not
> apply). If the destination type is bool, this is a boolean conversion
> (see below).
>
> A prvalue of integer or unscoped enumeration type can be
> converted to a prvalue of any floating-point type. If the value cannot
> be represented correctly, it is implementation defined whether the
> closest higher or the closest lower representable value will be
> selected, although if IEEE arithmetic is supported, rounding defaults
> to nearest. If the value cannot fit into the destination type, the
> behavior is undefined. If the source type is bool, the value false is
> converted to zero, and the value true is converted to one.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is not guaranteed to be able to hold the value of a pointer. In your case I believe `intptr_t` would work.

Answer (score -1):

You lose precision, it's fairly self explanatory.

In this case there's 2 reasons why you do.

1. An integer only has 4 bytes, whereas a double has 8, meaning you can't put the entire double into the integer. (In reality it's implementation defined)
2. A double has decimal numbers, an integer does not, so an integer simply cannot hold information about decimal numbers.

The reason that line errors is because you're trying to cast a pointer to an integer, which is not possible, what you meant to do is `j = (int)*p;`

There's several bad practices in your code.

1. using namespace std;
   [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#using-namespace-std

[How to use an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712076/how-to-use-an-iterator/2712125#2712125) (example of it causing problems)

[Confusion about pointers and references in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402789/confusion-about-pointers-and-references-in-c) (another example of it causing problems; using std::swap; would cause the same exact problem as well)

2. C style casts
   This is `(type)`, in your case specifically `(int)`
   There are 2 main casts that should be used in C++, static_cast and reinterpret_cast.
   (There are 2 more types, const_cast and dynamic_cast, but these are irrelevant in this case, and const_cast should almost never be used)

Both take a template parameter to the resulting type.

In this case, you could probably `i = static_cast<int>(d);`

For the second cast, j =, you should (in reality you shouldn't cast pointers to different types)

`j = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(p);`

Of course, casting doubles to integers isn't considered good, but this should fix your compiler error.

Comment: `*reinterpret_cast<int*>(p)` is UB and should not be used.

Comment: Agreed, it should not be used, agreed.

He shouldn't be casting doubles to integers at all. I realise this is undefined behavior i just wanted to give an example on reinterpret_cast, he's better off doing 
`static_cast<int>(*p)` in this case.

Comment: Probably, I'm missing something, but `*reinterpret_cast<int*>(p)` and `static_cast<int>(*p)` do completely different things.

Comment: Correct again, I wanted to give an example on reinterpret_cast, since I had just given the 2 main cast types in C++.

Comment: "An integer only has 4 bytes, whereas a double has 8." Not necessarily.

Comment: I wanted to say it's `implementation defined` but that would confuse him more, since he's clearly a beginner, though, ill add it to the post

Comment: @Bapo: An answer ought not be targeted solely at the OP: it ought to be correct too.

Comment: I also take issue with "A double has decimal numbers". Saying that a "double is a subset of the set of real numbers" is better.

Comment: I disagree that's better for explaining the fact that an integer does not have decimals, so I won't be editing that.

Comment: _"you should"_ then _"Agreed, it should not be used, agreed"_

Comment: @Bapo: But saying that a `double` can hold decimal numbers is misleading. They can't in general: in that respect they are no better than an integral type. Sorry but the downvote stays.

Comment: I mean, I didn't write this for reputation lol, keep the downvote there, couldn't care less.